# SharePoint 2010 web service API in the cloud (BPOS / Office 265)

Tags: web-services, sharepoint-2010, office365

[The SOAP web service API for SharePoint is documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee705814.aspx) by Microsoft, however there is no explicit mention of BPOS / Office 365 / Microsoft's cloud offering. Google isn't helping much, so I thought I'd ask here:

1. Is there any documentation on consuming Web Services hosted in Microsoft's cloud?
2. Are there any differences in authentication or using web services from a non-cloud SharePoint installation compared with a cloud solution? I'm particularly interested in authentication and how the cloud integrates with an Enterpris's existing authentication infrastructure?
3. Does the [Authentication class of the Web Service API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcauthentication.aspx) abstract away all authentication details and therefore the web service client should have no concern about how authentication is actually achieved (it just sends a username, password and checks the [LoginResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcauthentication.loginresult) returned from the web service)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no easy way. And no way documented by Microsoft.
Look here for someone who did it and share his code:
http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/How-to-do-active-authentication-to-Office-365-and-SharePoint-Online.aspx

Basically, here is what it does:

- Get login url
- Post the form
- Get the cookie from SPO
- Insert it in every call you make